# Tkinter: Assign Variables with Value with a Button Click

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I would like to make a Button that assign a new variable with a value in a compact form.

I tried this:

```
def whichButton(self, _var, _pressedButton):
    self._var = _pressedButton 

def checkScooter(self):
    self.checkScooter = Button(window, text="Standard", command=lambda: self.whichButton(edition, 1))
    self.checkScooter(row=1, column=0)

def checkAbonnement(self):
    self.checkAbonnement = Button(window, text="Gold", command=lambda: self.whichButton(abonnement, 3))
    self.checkAbonnement(row=1, column=0)
```

It just gives me an error, that "edition" is not defined, but I want the Button to define it

Any tips?

Comment: It isn't good practise to do that. Why not split it in 2 functions?

Comment: I edited it, you mean it like that?

Comment: What I means is to split it so the 2 buttons call 2 different functions. Those functions would be trivial to program if you do that.

Comment: Wouldn't it overfill the program?
If you would make a new function everytime?
Edit: I would only have to do 2 Functions for my program but if you got multiple of those?

Comment: It will make it more readable. If your program isn't readable there is no way of debugging it later. If you really want to do it your way, I can write an answer but it's really ugly and if a bug appears, ...

Comment: Then I will do it with the functions, thanks bud :)

Comment: No problem. By the way, just try running `import this` in python. It is built in and you should read it. It specifically says: *Readability counts.*

Comment: Assigning to `self._var` sets an attribute literally named `_var`  The parameter to your method of the same name has absolutely nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request to set a *new* variable is odd, and probably not the right solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve.

That being said, you can use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=setattr#setattr) to set the value based on the name of a variable. That variable doesn't have to exist. For example, to set the variable `self.edition` to `1` you can do `setattr(self, "edition", 1)`.

Therefore, you can pass in the string name of the variable to your `whichButton` function, and use `setattr` to set a variable with that name.

It would look something like this:

```
def whichButton(self, _var, _pressedButton):
    setattr(self, _var, _pressedButton)
...
self.checkScooter = Button(..., command=lambda: self.whichButton("edition", 1))
...
self.checkAbonnement = Button(..., command=lambda: self.whichButton("abonnement", 3))
```

In the above code, clicking either button will either set `self.edition` or `self.abonnement`.

---

There is almost certainly a better solution to your problem, but your question doesn't provide any details about what problem you're really trying to solve. A simple mprovement over this would be to use a dictionary to hold your "new" variables rather than creating literally new variables.

You can do that by defining a dictionary in your `__init__` and then setting it in your `whichButton` function.

It would look something like this:

```
class Something:
    def __init__(self):
        self._vars = {}
    def whichButton(self, name, new_value):
        self._vars[name] = new_value
```

This has the advantage that all of these special variables exist in a single data structure, separate from the object. That means that it would be impossible to accidentally overwrite instance variables.